# Web UI Testing - Cross Browser and Operating System

Tags: windows, macos, web, coded-ui-tests, ui-testing

I've been looking at approaches for automating UI tests on our web applications. My question is:

Are there any tools out there that will allow me to replay UI tests in multiple browsers and multiple operating systems (in particular IE, FF, Chome and Safari on Windows and OSx)?

Thanks,
Mark

Answer (score 0):

You can try: 
[Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/) or [Watir](http://watir.com/) or [iMacros](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IMacros)

These allow you to either record a user journey (Selenium, IMacros) or to program in a user journey.

Watir comes in a number of flavours to fit your programming needs, ruby, dotnet, java, etc.

Comment: I tried selenium, but the replay of tests is very hit and miss on my dev app. I can't find enough evidence that WatiN is easy enough to use to warrant spending time on invesitgation. Do you know any good introduction screencasts?

Comment: I dont know of any Watin only vids but the following was useful to me. http://userinexperience.com/?p=289. It mainly covers specflow but shows how simple Watin is to use. There is a port of Watin to run on OSX but Im not sure how easy it is to run.